# EXTJS GridPanel and Column Data defaults

Tags: extjs, extjs3

I have a a `gridpanel` that has the following fields:

```
Name ID Address Home_Phone Cell
```

Some records that return to the store may not have any data for some of these fields, rather then display an empty column for that record in the grid I would like to show a default value of `N/A`.

> So I would have

```
Name     ID   Address      Home_Phone    Cell
Shaun    2    My Address     N/A          N/A
```

> Rather then:

```
Name     ID   Address      Home_Phone    Cell
Shaun    2    My Address
```

I know of two ways to do this:

1. In the back end if the field doesn't exists return a "N/A" for that column in the JSON.
2. Create a template with a method that check if the record doesn't contain the value return "N/A".

My question is, is there an easier way to tell the `grid` column if no value is found in the record display the default `N/A`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can add a renderer for your columns. You either add a renderer for each column or you can define your own column if you have more columns with this behaviour.

//add this for each column config (works for null values and empty strings)

```
{
    renderer: function(value){
        if (Ext.isEmpty(value)) {
            return 'N\\A';
        }
        return value;
    }
}
```

or add the renderer to a component that extends the column and use that throughout the application.
It's easier to do this on the front end rather then modifying the backend and sent extra unnecessary data like 'N\A'.

Hope It helps.

Comment: you have missed closing brace ')' in your condition: `if (Ext.isEmpty(value) {`. Also you should escape slash in such way: `'N\\A'`

Comment: Wouldn't it have been more useful to edit this 4 year old answer instead of this comment?

Comment: your answer was accepted as the best answer - so lead it to appropriate form. (If I made such mistakes I fully expected that such answer will be reprimanded by the 'other guys' - And I was encountered such cases). Don't like downvotes ?! Me, too.

Comment: You really are encouraged on stackoverflow to edit answers and improve them, not just rant on some code error. By the way maybe it was the best answer because people need the ideea not the exact code! I don't care about the downvote ( even if that means the answer was not useful), I would have apreciated more to receive a notification that your answer was edited. Would have apreciated that.

Comment: I have edited your post (but without any upvote).(Someone's really cares about your downvote cause in response to your downvoting I was downvoted too. I thought that was you)